# NGINX issue with converted PFX cert

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, pfx

I'm trying to convert a pfx cert to a PEM/Key style cert so I can use it with NGINX. For some reason though, I keep getting this error:

nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate: PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)

I've tried numerous formats, but I can't figure it out.
Beginning of the pem file looks like this:

-----BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE-----

I've also tried -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- as it came initially after I converted it with openSSL- I've tried numerous combinations of commands, but honestly I'm not quite sure what I'm doing here- new to SSL cert manipulation and the docs aren't making a whole ton of sense to me.

Comment: Have you seen [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447752/what-does-begin-trusted-certificate-in-a-certificate-mean)? It requires the certificate + rules.

Comment: Seems you can *convert* the certificate using `openssl x509 -trustout ...` options. The program probably expects (a possibly empty) SEQUENCE in the binary encoding **after** the encoding of the certificate.

Comment: (@Maarten) The error message 'expecting TRUSTED CERTIFICATE' is misleading; PEM_read_X509_AUX can read _either_ the plain-cert format `BEGIN/END [X.509] CERTIFICATE` or OpenSSL's special format `BEGIN/END TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`, and the former is more common by far; but if _neither_ is found, the error message cites only the second. OP: examine your file to see _exactly_ what is on the BEGIN line, including any invisible characters like space, tab, BOM or bidi. On Unix use `cat -vET` or `od -c`; on Windows-non-WSL powershell `format-hex`.

Comment: Note that PEM also has a specific line length and base 64 encoding, which isn't shown in the question. You can see more information [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468) and the part specifically about certificates [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-5). Thanks Dave, that's an annoying error message indeed.